# Insert hyphens if there is a string break AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Inside a `div` of fixed *width*, a string is being bind to it. The string can be short as well as long.

I want whenever the original string breaks, it should insert a *hyphen*, for every line except the last line.

**Eg:** If the string is *"misconception"* and it breaks at *misc*, then it should appear like ->

```
misc-
once-
ptio-
n
```

instead of like this ->

```
misc
once
ptio
n
```

**Note:** I have tried with the following CSS:

```
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
```

but the problem is that `hyphens` work only with dictionary words. In my case, the string can be anything, example: name, junk-string, etc., so `hyphens` wont work in my case.

Refer to the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/6jcs8xL5/) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the above issue through scripting in *AngularJS* itself, requiring no CSS.

**Code below:**

*JS:*

```
  $scope.data = "Loremipsumdolorsitametexeamdictasmeliuslaboramus Duoadverearinteresset";
  var text = $scope.data;
  var array = text.split('');
  len = 18;

  var newtext = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newtext += array[i];
    if (i % len == 0 && i > 1) {
      newtext += '-</br>';
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = newtext;
```

*HTML:*

```
<div class="test" id="text"></div>
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/68oAh1zq3rruN7QqG3W6?p=preview)

Comment: `if ((i+1)%len == 0)`. Other case, it will wrap first line at char 19